# query avoding subselect

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery

I have this query and it's very slow. Can i write this query in other way by avoiding subselects for example?

Also i tried adding composite index on

```
MyIndex(kategorije_id,izdvojen,izdvojen_kad,datum)
```

but it doesent use it when i explain this query so is there another index that i can use to speed up this query?

```
SELECT artikli.datum AS brojx, artikli.izdvojen AS i, artikli.izdvojen_kad AS ii, artikli.name
FROM artikli
WHERE artikli.izbrisan =0
AND artikli.prodano !=3
AND artikli.zavrseno =0
AND artikli.od_id !=0
AND kategorije_id
IN ( 18 )
AND (
SELECT count( * )
FROM artikli_polja, polja
WHERE polja.id_kat = artikli.kategorije_id
AND artikli_polja.id_polja = polja.id
AND artikli_polja.id_artikal = artikli.id
AND polja.name = "godiste"
AND artikli_polja.valueInt >= "1993"
) >0
AND (
SELECT count( * )
FROM artikli_polja, polja
WHERE polja.id_kat = artikli.kategorije_id
AND artikli_polja.id_polja = polja.id
AND artikli_polja.id_artikal = artikli.id
AND polja.name = "godiste"
AND artikli_polja.valueInt <= "2000"
) >0
ORDER BY i DESC , ii DESC , brojx DESC
LIMIT 140 , 35
```

Comment: `Limit x offset y`, gets slower as the offset increases.

Comment: Your current (slow) query will return an artikli table row that meets all the other criteria and has artikli_polja rows with valueInt >= '1993' and <= '2000', even if those conditions don't occur in the **same** artikli_polja row. For example, if one row has valueInt 1990 and another has valueInt 2010, the linked artikli row will be selected. Is this the behavior you want? Alternatively, do you want the artikli row to be selected only if it meets the other criteria and there is at least one artikli_polja row with a valueInt that is >= 1993 and <= 2000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT a.datum AS brojx, a.izdvojen AS i, a.izdvojen_kad AS ii, a.name 
FROM artikli a
WHERE a.izbrisan =0
AND a.prodano !=3
AND a.zavrseno =0
AND a.od_id !=0
AND a.kategorije_id = 18
AND EXISTS 
   (select 'X' 
   from artikli_polja ap,
   JOIN polja p
   ON ap.id_polja = p.id AND p.id_kat = a.kategorije_id
   AND ap.id_artikal = a.id
   AND p.name = 'godiste'
   AND ap.valueInt >= 1993 AND ap.valueInt <= 2000
   );
```

Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT a.datum AS brojx, a.izdvojen AS i, a.izdvojen_kad AS ii, a.name FROM artikli a
  JOIN artikli_polja ap
    ON ap.id_artikal = a.id
  JOIN polja p
    ON ap.id_polja = p.id AND p.id_kat = a.kategorije_id
WHERE
  a.izbrisan =0
  AND a.prodano !=3
  AND a.zavrseno =0
  AND a.od_id !=0
  AND kategorije_id = 18
  AND p.name = 'godiste'
  AND ap.valueInt >= 1993 AND ap.valueInt <= 2000;
```

I have removed ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses from the query; try to work out this query firstly.

Comment: Funny, i allways get 1 to 3 more rows on your query when i do mysql_num_rows on both type of queries.

Comment: I'd suggest you to find these records and try to understand the reason.

Comment: This query is a little different than original. It tests if particular row is between 1993 and 2000, but the original query tests if there are matching rows above 1993 and if there are matching rows below 2000.

Comment: Yes, really. They are a bit different.